# pycocotools (core dumped). Is it an AVX issue?

Tags: python, cpu, avx

I try to use pycocotools from python:

```
$ ipython
Python 3.6.5 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Apr  6 2018, 13:39:56) 
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 6.5.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]: from pycocotools.coco import COCO
Segmentation Error (core dumped)
```

Can this be related to my CPU missing AVX instructions (xeon E5520) ?

Comment: please add information about your operating system and how you installed `pycocotools`. `pycocotools` includes compiled c code, this is the usual suspect if an import crashes with a `Segmentation Error`.

Answer (score 1):

In case `pycocotools` has issues with the compiled part, please run

- `pip uninstall -y pycocotools`
- `pip install --no-binary :all: pycocotools`

This should compile the C code shipped with `pycoctools` on your machine.

Comment: make from PythonAPI directory didn't improve: https://github.com/cocodataset/cocoapi/issues/209#issue-354308665

Answer (score 1):

If your program tried to execute AVX instructions on a CPU that doesn't support them, you'd get SIGILL (Illegal Instruction) on OSes like Linux.

"Segmentation Error" seems to be some kind of custom error message, because the normal string is always "Segmentation *Fault*".  It's *possible* that there's a bug or stricter alignment requirement in the non-AVX version of code that's selected at runtime; runtime dispatch would be a plausible mechanism for code working on an AVX CPU and segfaulting without AVX.